# call a method on variable

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4

I have a question, I have two methods and I would want to call on my second method the first one in a variable.

How is it possible?

Is it good what I did?

```
def ping_check_url(url)
  check = Net::Ping::External.new(url)
  check.ping?     
end 

def get_info_yml_file
  config = YAML.load_file('config_url.yaml')
  config.each do |key, value|
    key = key
    ping_check_url.(url = value['url_web_site'])
    # ping_check_url(url) 
    puts " #{key} : #{@url} "
  end
end
```

Comment: `key = key` is not needed. It will help if you show us the contents (or an example) of how *config_url.yaml* looks

Answer (score 1):

You should do

```
ping_check_url(value['url_web_site'])
```

instead of

```
ping_check_url.(url = value['url_web_site'])
```

Answer (score 0):

Please try this

```
def ping_check_url(url)
  check = Net::Ping::External.new(url)
  check.ping?     
end 

def get_info_yml_file
  config = YAML.load_file('config_url.yaml')
  config.each do |key, value|
    key = key
    ping_check_url(value['url_web_site'])
    # ping_check_url(url) 
    puts " #{key} : #{@url} "
  end
end
```

Also, you are not initializing `@url` anywhere but using it in `get_info_yml_file`. it would always return `nil`